# Form Action Page Not Found

Tags: forms, perl, http-status-code-404

I am playing around a bit with Perl and auto-filling out forms. However, when I view the source code and paste the "action" URL of a form into my browser, it goes to a "Page Not Found". How could this be? If data is able to be submitted to a page then wouldn't the page have to exist? Or am i just missing something?

For instance, the HTML looks like:

```
<form action="/Pages/somepage">
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

So if i go to http://thewebserver.com/formPage/Pages/somepage it simply displays a "Page Not Found" error.

Thanks.

Comment: With absolutely no information to go on, I am going to go out on a limb here and ask you to consider the possibility, however remote it might seem to you, that you are, indeed, *just missing something*. We don't know what because we have no idea what you are looking at.

Comment: It might be page not found, it might be relative paths. It might just not exist in the first place. But more detail is needed before this question becomes answerable.

Comment: sorry for the lack of info...the thing is that the form works from the website. However, if I go to the action URL, the page is "not found". Is there a possibility that the form redirects to another page when submitted?

Answer (score 0):

If the form action is "/Pages/somepage", then the correct full URL will be  http://thewebserver.com/Pages/somepage, not  http://thewebserver.com/formPage/Pages/somepage. Not sure where you got that "formPage" from.